# Cant create workspace TFS from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, tfs

I installed the TFS plugin (http://java.visualstudio.com/) for Android Studio but I can not connect to the server. Any extra ideas? Thank you!

evidence image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can be interpreted to be the result of self-signed certificate.  If the certificate in use is Self-signed or any other certificate that is private to the internal network.

Java doesn’t trust such certificates and for which, we can [**import the cert**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail/11617655#11617655) into the trust store and make it to work.

> The link explains how the certificate import works in a Linux machine
>   (which is also applicable for Windows).
>
> the “keytool” is under “\bin\keytool.exe”, and
>
> the “cacerts” trust store is under
>   “\jre\lib\security\cacerts”.
>
> should be the jre/jdk installation used by IntelliJ.
>
> This should have resolved the above TFS connectivity failure.

Reference this article: [Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/12/19/error-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/)

And this thread: [How to properly import a selfsigned certificate into Java keystore that is available to all Java applications by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail/11617655#11617655)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll keep investigating. Regards!