# Turn off SSL Certificate verification

Tags: java, web-crawler, stormcrawler

Working on Storm Crawler 1.12.1 and Elastic search 6.5.x. My Crawler is running on `http://localhost:8080` and  Elastic search running on `https://localhost:9200`.I am trying to crawl a website.During URL injection process  I am facing `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem` error and check [the detailed error here](https://github.com/an-snatcher/SSLError_StormCrawler).

I tried for OKHttp and added `https.protocol.implementation: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.okhttp.HttpProtocol"` in crawler-conf.yaml.

How can I turn off the certificate verification temporarily.

Comment: There is no fetching during the injection so switching to OKHttp is not going to have any effect. 
This is more likely to be an issue with the connection to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @julien-nioche indicated in his comment: StormCrawler does *not* fetch in the process of URL injection.

The `SSLHandshakeException` most likely originates from your ElasticSearch instance. Is your ElasticSearch really running on `HTTPS` as indicated by `https://localhost:9200`?

The stacktrace indicates that the certificate path could not be validated.

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

To resolve this issue, you could add the certificate to your local key-store. For details on this subject, you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail). Another possibility would be to disable `HTTPS` on the ElasticSearch instance for your local development setup.