# Gradle on VirtualBox Ubuntu Host windows 10 behind internet proxy, getting rg.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Windows-ROOT not found

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle on ubuntu (vBox on windows 10). Behind internet proxy. Getting following error.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':master-service'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':master-service:classpath'.
> Could not download spotbugs-gradle-plugin.jar (gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:2.0.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/github/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/2.0.0/spotbugs-gradle-plugin-2.0.0.jar'.
> > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Windows-ROOT not found
> Could not download spring-boot-gradle-plugin.jar (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE)
> > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar'.
> > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Windows-ROOT not found
> Could not download spring-boot-loader-tools.jar (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:2.2.2.RELEASE)
> > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-loader-tools-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar'.
> > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Windows-ROOT not found
> Could not download dependency-management-plugin.jar (io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.8.RELEASE)
> > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/spring/gradle/dependency-management-plugin/1.0.8.RELEASE/dependency-management-plugin-1.0.8.RELEASE.jar'.
> > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Windows-ROOT not found
> Could not download commons-compress.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.19)
> > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.19/commons-compress-1.19.jar'.
> > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Windows-ROOT not found
> Could not download spring-core.jar (org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.2.RELEASE)
> > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar'.
> > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Windows-ROOT not found
> Could not download spring-jcl.jar (org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.2.RELEASE)
> > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar'.
> > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Windows-ROOT not found

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are behind a company firewall of some sort. Some things you can try:

1. Configure Gradle's HTTPS Proxy: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy
2. If your company has an internal Maven repository/mirrors Maven Central internally, then you should use that repository instead of the public/internet Gradle one. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories
3. Make sure your local JDK installation has your company's root SSL certificate, if one exists. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail) answer.