# Java Web Start rejecting self signed certificate

Tags: java

All:

```
  Ran th Java Web Start and attempted to launch 3rd party applet.  Got
```

a warning that the self signed certificate was rejected.  I went to Start > Control Panel > Java > Security tab >  added the URL to exception list with HIGH radio button clicked > clicked on OK
button.  Reran the same JWS, got the same error message.  Running with jre 1.8_241 What gives ???

Comment: Maybe tell Java to trust the cert instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail

Comment: This is the whole point of security.  Accepting self-signed certificates blindly would eliminate all web security.  You must add the certificate's CA public key to the Java keychain.  Also, JavaWebStart was deprecated in Java 9 and REMOVED in Java 11.  It is a dead end.